# xampp's apache is not starting

Tags: windows-8.1, xampp

I have installed xampp in windows 8.1 . But while i start its control pannel it says,"api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll missing" . I tried installing

```
    vc_redist.x64.exe
```

but its not installing properly. 
It display follwing log file:

```
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:17]i001: Burn v3.7.3813.0, Windows v6.3 (Build 9600: Service Pack 0), path: C:\Users\Suzan\Downloads\Programs\vc_redist.x64.exe, cmdline: ''
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:18]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\Suzan\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_amd64_20170715180618.log'
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:18]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'C:\Users\Suzan\Downloads\Programs\vc_redist.x64.exe'
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:18]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder' to value 'C:\Users\Suzan\Downloads\Programs\'
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:18]i100: Detect begin, 10 packages
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:18]i000: File search: windows_uCRT_DetectKey, did not find path: C:\Windows\system32\ucrtbase.dll
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:18]i000: File search: windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists, did not find path: C:\Windows\system32\ucrtbase.dll
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:18]i000: Setting numeric variable 'windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists' to value 0
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:18]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.3 AND NOT VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:18]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.3 AND VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:18]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.2 AND NOT VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:18]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.2 AND VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:18]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.1 AND NOT VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:18]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.1 AND VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:18]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.0 AND NOT VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:18]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.0 AND VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:18]i101: Detected package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, state: Present, cached: Complete
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:18]i101: Detected package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64, state: Present, cached: Complete
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:18]i101: Detected package: Windows81_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:18]i101: Detected package: Windows81_x64, state: Absent, cached: Complete
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:18]i101: Detected package: Windows8_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:18]i101: Detected package: Windows8_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:18]i101: Detected package: Windows7_MSU_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:18]i101: Detected package: Windows7_MSU_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:18]i101: Detected package: WindowsVista_MSU_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:18]i101: Detected package: WindowsVista_MSU_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:18]i052: Condition 'VersionNT64 >= v6.0 OR (VersionNT64 = v5.2 AND ServicePackLevel >= 1)' evaluates to true.
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:18]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:20]i200: Plan begin, 10 packages, action: Repair
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:20]i052: Condition '(VersionNT64)' evaluates to true.
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:20]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_vcRuntimeMinimum_x64' to value 'C:\Users\Suzan\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_amd64_20170715180618_000_vcRuntimeMinimum_x64.log'
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:20]i052: Condition '(VersionNT64)' evaluates to true.
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:20]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_vcRuntimeAdditional_x64' to value 'C:\Users\Suzan\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_amd64_20170715180618_001_vcRuntimeAdditional_x64.log'
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:20]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.3 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:20]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows81_x86
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:20]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.3 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to true.
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:20]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows81_x64
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:20]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.2 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:20]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows8_x86
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:20]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.2 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:20]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows8_x64
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:20]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.1 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:20]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows7_MSU_x86
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:20]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.1 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:20]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows7_MSU_x64
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:20]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.0 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:20]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: WindowsVista_MSU_x86
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:20]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.0 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:20]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: WindowsVista_MSU_x64
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:20]i201: Planned package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, state: Present, default requested: Repair, ba requested: Repair, execute: Repair, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Register
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:20]i201: Planned package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64, state: Present, default requested: Repair, ba requested: Repair, execute: Repair, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Register
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:20]i201: Planned package: Windows81_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:20]i201: Planned package: Windows81_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Repair, ba requested: Repair, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:20]i201: Planned package: Windows8_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:20]i201: Planned package: Windows8_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:20]i201: Planned package: Windows7_MSU_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:20]i201: Planned package: Windows7_MSU_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:20]i201: Planned package: WindowsVista_MSU_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:20]i201: Planned package: WindowsVista_MSU_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:20]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:20]i300: Apply begin
            [0964:0C48][2017-07-15T18:06:22]i360: Creating a system restore point.
            [0964:0C48][2017-07-15T18:06:22]i361: Created a system restore point.
            [0964:0C48][2017-07-15T18:06:22]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{e9d78d68-c26c-4da7-9158-99355d8ef3ad}, resume: Active, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
            [0964:0C7C][2017-07-15T18:06:22]i304: Verified existing payload: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{8D4F7A6D-6B81-3DC8-9C21-6008E4866727}v14.10.25017\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_amd64\vc_runtimeMinimum_x64.msi.
            [0964:0C7C][2017-07-15T18:06:22]i304: Verified existing payload: cab5046A8AB272BF37297BB7928664C9503 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{8D4F7A6D-6B81-3DC8-9C21-6008E4866727}v14.10.25017\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_amd64\cab1.cab.
            [0964:0C7C][2017-07-15T18:06:22]i304: Verified existing payload: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{E512788E-C50B-3858-A4B9-73AD5F3F9E93}v14.10.25017\packages\vcRuntimeAdditional_amd64\vc_runtimeAdditional_x64.msi.
            [0964:0C7C][2017-07-15T18:06:22]i304: Verified existing payload: cab2C04DDC374BD96EB5C8EB8208F2C7C92 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{E512788E-C50B-3858-A4B9-73AD5F3F9E93}v14.10.25017\packages\vcRuntimeAdditional_amd64\cab1.cab.
            [0964:0C7C][2017-07-15T18:06:23]i304: Verified existing payload: Windows81_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\3ACBF3890FC9C8A6F3D2155ECF106028E5F55164\packages\Patch\x64\Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.msu.
            [0964:0C48][2017-07-15T18:06:23]i301: Applying execute package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, action: Repair, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{8D4F7A6D-6B81-3DC8-9C21-6008E4866727}v14.10.25017\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_amd64\vc_runtimeMinimum_x64.msi, arguments: ' MSIFASTINSTALL="7" NOVSUI="1"'
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:23]i319: Applied execute package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, result: 0x0, restart: None
            [0964:0C48][2017-07-15T18:06:23]i325: Registering dependency: {e9d78d68-c26c-4da7-9158-99355d8ef3ad} on package provider: Microsoft.VS.VC_RuntimeMinimumVSU_amd64,v14, package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64
            [0964:0C48][2017-07-15T18:06:23]i301: Applying execute package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64, action: Repair, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{E512788E-C50B-3858-A4B9-73AD5F3F9E93}v14.10.25017\packages\vcRuntimeAdditional_amd64\vc_runtimeAdditional_x64.msi, arguments: ' MSIFASTINSTALL="7" NOVSUI="1"'
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:24]i319: Applied execute package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64, result: 0x0, restart: None
            [0964:0C48][2017-07-15T18:06:24]i325: Registering dependency: {e9d78d68-c26c-4da7-9158-99355d8ef3ad} on package provider: Microsoft.VS.VC_RuntimeAdditionalVSU_amd64,v14, package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64
            [0964:0C48][2017-07-15T18:06:24]i301: Applying execute package: Windows81_x64, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\3ACBF3890FC9C8A6F3D2155ECF106028E5F55164\packages\Patch\x64\Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.msu, arguments: '"C:\Windows\SysNative\wusa.exe" "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\3ACBF3890FC9C8A6F3D2155ECF106028E5F55164\packages\Patch\x64\Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.msu" /quiet /norestart'
            [0964:0C48][2017-07-15T18:06:26]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to execute MSU package.
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:26]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to configure per-machine MSU package.
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:26]i319: Applied execute package: Windows81_x64, result: 0x80240017, restart: None
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:26]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to execute MSU package.
            [0964:0C48][2017-07-15T18:06:26]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{e9d78d68-c26c-4da7-9158-99355d8ef3ad}, resume: ARP, restart: None, disable resume: No
            [0964:0C48][2017-07-15T18:06:26]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{e9d78d68-c26c-4da7-9158-99355d8ef3ad}, resume: ARP, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
            [0C14:06D4][2017-07-15T18:06:26]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80240017, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```

I also tried installing all the updates in windows. How can i solve this issue? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be two strategies for solving this problem:

- Apparently, the missing "api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll"  is generally installed with a Windows update, especially for pre-Windows 10 machines. According to the internet, to resolve this issue, you may wish to download and install the [Update for Universal C Runtime in Windows from Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows-c0514201-7fe6-95a3-b0a5-287930f3560c) (assuming Windows isn't doing what it needs to).
- If you are relatively sure you have this update, are hesitant to do this or are still having issues, you may need to pick up the [latest Visual C++ redistributables](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/) and manually update them yourself. This may particularly apply in your case since the process your attempting seems to be uncooperative.

Here are the direct links for VS 2017 [64 bit](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=746572) and [32 bit](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=746571) versions.

Here is a direct link for the [latest VS 2015 Update 3 redistributables including 64-bit and 32-bit versions.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52685)

Regarding the redistributables, the error your receiving can be caused by both VS 2015 and VS 2017, so you may want to install the redistributables for both.

Also, though I would be a bit careful with this, if you are given the option to uninstall the redistributables when running the installer (so you can reinstall them afterwards), this is typically better than "Repairing" them.